# GridSearchCV doesn't give best score on same dataset

Tags: python, gridsearchcv

I am trying to get the best score using GridSearchCV with the below code.

```
params = {'C':[15,20,25],'epsilon':[.003,.005,.008],'gamma':[.0001,.0003,.0006]}
svr = SVR()
grid=GridSearchCV(svr,param_grid=params)
grid.fit(X,train_labels)
gridCV = make_pipeline(RobustScaler(),grid)
gridCV.fit(X,train_labels)
grid.best_score_
grid.best_params_
#Output - 
0.9014615123000982
{'C': 25, 'epsilon': 0.005, 'gamma': 0.0003}
```

Now if I try the same code with a specific subset of the hyper parameters I get a better score as below. Why is the GridSearchCV not giving the best score?

```
svr = SVR()
grid=GridSearchCV(svr,param_grid={'C':[20],'epsilon':[.008],'gamma':[.0003]})
grid.fit(X,train_labels)
gridCV = make_pipeline(RobustScaler(),grid)
gridCV.fit(X,train_labels)
grid.best_score_
#Output - .9010315734981053
```

Comment: Hey, I think you are misreading the scores. Clearly, the "best score" produced by the first Grid Search (0.9014) is better than the score produced by specific hyperparams (0.9010). I mean I wouldn't even consider these scores as any different. But if you are trying to compare it with a specific precision, the first Grid Search is still better....

Answer (score 0):

Default scoring function for SVR is R² (see [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html))

This means the higher the better.

`0.9014615123000982` is higher than `0.9010315734981053`

`GridSearchCV` is giving you the best solution